# Maven: "dependency vs module "

Tags: maven, maven-3

I would like to know the difference between the two. From what I understand the dependency needs a version etc but modules can be defined without the version and it takes the parent's version. Is there more to it?

Answer (score 15):

A dependency and a module are different concepts.

---

From the [Maven book](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) about dependencies:

> Maven can manage both internal and external dependencies. An external dependency for a Java project might be a library such as Plexus, the Spring Framework, or Log4J. An internal dependency is illustrated by a web application project depending on another project that contains service classes, model objects, or persistence logic.

Put simply, a dependency is saying: *"To build my project, I need to **use** this library"*.

A dependency in Maven is defined by its [coordinates](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-more-coordinates), that are made of 4 elements:

- `groupId`: The `groupId` groups a set of related artifacts. It generally resemble a Java package name. For example, the `groupId` `org.apache.maven` is the base `groupId` for all artifacts produced by the Apache Maven project.
- `artifactId`: The `artifactId` is the project main identifier. When you generate an artifact, this artifact is going to be named with the `artifactId`. The `artifactId`, `groupId` combination must be unique. In other words, you can't have two separate projects with the same `artifactId` and `groupId`. Furthermore, you can't have the same `artifactId` for a given `groupId`.
- `version`: When an artifact is released, it is released with a version number, such as "1.0", "1.1.1", or "1.1.2-alpha-01". You can also use what is known as a snapshot version for a component which is under development, like "1.0-SNAPSHOT".
- `classifier`: A classifier is not needed and is generally not used. It is only relevant when you need to produce several artifacts from a single project: it then serves as a distinction in the file names, that otherwise would be made simply with the `artifactId` and `version` and thus conflicts.

In the [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies), it looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.some.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

This declares a dependency to the `my-project` library identified by the given coordinates.

---

A module is used in the context of [multi-module Maven project](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit). From the Maven book:

> A multimodule project simply manages a group of other subprojects or modules. [...] When setting up a multimodule project, you are simply telling a project that its build should include the specified modules. Multimodule builds are to be used to group modules together in a single build.

Put simply, having a module is saying *"To build my project, I need to **build** this project"*.

In the [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation), this is done like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>my-project</module>
    <module>another-project</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

You are saying that this project, identified by `org.codehaus.mojo:my-parent:2.0:pom`, declared 2 modules which are `my-project` and `another-project`. Thus, when you build `my-parent`, those two modules will also be built.

Comment: Thanks, so I assume the included module/s needs to define a pom itself (it being a separate project in itself) whereas a dependency could just be an artifact in the repository that does not need to have a pom ? thanks.

Comment: @SoltanG Well almost, if it's a dependency in your maven repo, it should have its own pom to describe other libraries that itself may depend upon, so that maven will know to download them as well when building your project. The dependencies of your dependencies are called [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). However the pom was defined by whoever made them and you only need to reference them in your project/modules and then magic will happen :-)

Comment: @Morfic thanks. I get it. If it's a dependency that we are maintain in our repo, we would have a Pom for it as well. Thanks.

Comment: could a module be used multiple times by different projects just as a dependency could be?

Comment: @jon Yes, because you would view it as a dependency in this case (notice the word "use"). What was a module at first can be used as a dependency for another module of the same build, or it can be used as a dependency of some other project entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually they're different, but they go hand-in-hand as well.

All of them parents, modules and libraries are *referenced*, by convention, using a *unique name* composed of a group-id, artifact-id and version. Unless you need otherwise (seldom happened to me) a module can indeed inherit its version from the parent but you do have the option of changing it.

A [maven module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) is like a sub-project of your project. It allows you to separate a big projects into smaller parts which can be managed individually, and in the end aggregated to build whatever you require. We could picture a car as the end product, being composed of several modules such as engine, wheels, chairs etc.

A dependency is a library your project or module requires to compile and/or function. Coming back to our car, it's true that it requires an engine module to function. However, the current version of the engine itself requires a certain type (version) of pistons to run correctly. Too big and they won't fit, too small and it won't work at all.

Applied to a java project, you can imagine having several modules which access a DB, call some web services, provide an UI, all of them linked together by their parent. Also the DB module will probably require a certain DB driver (MYSql, Oracle, etc), matching the version of the DB you're using, and the web service module an HTTP library, and so on.

Comment: Great explanation with the example of the car, makes it easier to visualize! thanks.

Comment: @SoltanG my pleasure, glad it was helpful. Combined with Tunaki's more technically detailed answer, you should have a clearer overview. Cheers

Comment: can a module be used multiple times by different projects just as a dependency could be?

Comment: @jon Do you have a specific case? Usually the resulting artifacts of the modules are installed in a company repository so they can be reused in other projects

Comment: actually i get it now. I have a 'pom' project that has 3 modules (data model, utils and helpers) and this pom project is the parent project for my API project. In the api, the 3 modules are now dependencies. Now i'm starting a new micro service project and i will also need the 3 same dependencies. No need for them as modules anymore.